# NoneType object is not iterable Error

Tags: python, append, iterable, nonetype

I have the task to write classes for Dijkstra's Algorithm. Though I'm not allowed to edit the Dijkstra class:

```
class Dijkstra():
# initialize with a string containing the root and a
# weighted edge list
def __init__(self, in_string):
    self.root, self.nnodes, self.adj_list = self.convert_to_adj_list(in_string)
    self.nodes = [Node(i) for i in range(self.nnodes)]
    self.nodes[self.root].key = 0
    self.heap = MinHeap(self.nodes)
# the input is expected to be a string 
# consisting of the number of nodes
# and a root followed by 
# vertex pairs with a non-negative weight
def convert_to_adj_list(self, in_string):
    nnodes, root, edges = in_string.split(';')
    root = int(root)
    nnodes = int(nnodes)
    adj_list = {}
    edges = [ map(int,wedge.split()) for wedge in edges.split(',')]
    for u,v,w in edges:
        (adj_list.setdefault(u,[])).append((v,w))
    for u in range(nnodes):
        adj_list.setdefault(u,[])
```

This is my problem:

```
string = '3; 0; 1 2 8, 2 0 5, 1 0 8, 2 1 3'
print(Dijkstra(string))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#321>", line 1, in <module>
    print(Dijkstra(string))
  File "C:\Users\TheDude\Downloads\dijkstra.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.root, self.nnodes, self.adj_list = self.convert_to_adj_list(in_string)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Do I assign `append`'s return value? And how can I fix it w/o editing 
`class Djikstra()`
Tanks for reading.

Comment: `convert_to_adj_list` returns `None`, since you didn't supply it with a return statement.

Comment: You should have a return value from `convert_to_adj_list`, so add `return adj_list` to the end of `convert_to_adj_list` definition.

Comment: So if I dont set a return value, any function will return None? 
I have to use the Dijkstra class so I need to contact a teacher to fix this.

Comment: BTW, `print(Dijkstra(string))` won't print info about the graph unless you provide the `Dijkstra` class with an appropriate `__repr__` or `__str__` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the assignment

```
    self.root, self.nnodes, self.adj_list = self.convert_to_adj_list(in_string)
```

to work, `convert_to_adj_list` has to return a tuple of three values to be unpacked into those three variables. Your method, however, returns nothing (thus implicitly returning `None`). Change your `convert_to_adj_list` method to something like this, then it should work:

```
def convert_to_adj_list(self, in_string):
    ... your code ...
    return root, nnodes, adj_list
```